# Storing an array of 500 NSStrings in an iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode4, nsstring

I want to make an iPhone app that fetches up to 500 NSStrings from a server, and then it stores that data for later use.

I believe that my options are to use NSUserDefaults, store them in an SQLite database, or store them in an XML file.

Is that correct? Is an array of 500 NSStrings large? Which method should I use?

Comment: CoreData (which might be overkill for you) is also an option, but the size of each of the 500 strings will determine if it is large or not.

Comment: "Is an array of 500 NSStrings large?" Since not all strings are created the same, the answer depends a lot on the lengths of your individual strings.

Comment: You could also store them in any plain text format such as a csv. I think that would have better performance than the other two. As for the strings, it depends on how long they are. There is a fixed cost for each which is all you can calculate without the length. If you're concerned with this fixed cost you could simple make one long string which is comma delimited. Then you reduce the overhead for each object. You can easily split them if you need to for processing.

Answer (score 3):

NSUserDefaults is meant for small amounts of application state and/or preferences.

SQLite is fine, but might be overkill if you're not using any RDBMS features.  Internally, Core Data uses SQLite.  If you're not interested in the object-graph, then Core Data is incredible overkill (and has a ton of overhead).

XML is meant for storing arbitrarily structured data.  Is there any inherent structure to your data or it purely just a list of 500 strings? If there's no structure, then XML is overkill and you have to parse it, which means a non-trivial amount of code.

Two more options you didn't mention are: plist and NSKeyedArchiver.  I'll leave it to you to read up on those.

Personally, I'd just go with a text file, but with the proviso that you haven't given enough information about the nature of the data or what you're going to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
NSArray initWithContentsOfFile:
```

and

```
NSArray writeToFile:
```

to easily store your Strings in a file.